# Extract the Pdf creation/modification date automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have lots of Pdf file weblink saved in my excel file from which I have to extract the date of pdf creation.
Checking One by one will take too much time. Is there any way to extract the creation date of all the files automatically in excel.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to extract the creation date in Excel directly, but it should be possible to write a program in a language of your choice, e.g., Python, to read the binary data in a PDF file and extract its creation date and time to a comma-separated value (CSV) text file wherein each line in the file contains the PDF file name and the timestamp. Invoke the program repeatedly with a batch script to automatically query hundreds of PDF files in a directory. The CSV file could then be easily read by Excel or any other spreadsheet program.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then the recorded PDF files are stored locally on your computer. If this is the case and you know the path of any single PDF file, you can use the `DateLastModified` property of a file and print the modification date as follows:

```
Dim fs, f, s
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.GetFile(filespec)
Debug.Print "Last Modification Date: " & f.DateLastModified
```

Whereas `filespec` represents the PDF file path

Futhermore check out following link: https://www.excelbanter.com/excel-discussion-misc-queries/125766-how-use-datelastmodified-property-vba.html